# how to show a bunch of numbers one by one on a seven segment display

Tags: logic-gates, 7segmentdisplay

The question is on the title. I just need a starting point like should I draw first the state diagram? I need to show the 150707926 on one seven segment display one by one by using logic gates. Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you allowed CD4017, 74HC47?

Comment: @Jasen no, only logic gates :/

Comment: depends on the display you choose. You need to read the datasheet. Does it have an input buffer? Might be as simple as putting a pin high/low to clear the buffer or display between characters.

Comment: @IC_Eng I don't know the details but I think we are given a standard (I mean simplest one) seven segment display with common anode.

Comment: Where is the data to be displayed coming from? Does logic gates include a shift register, or flip flops, or could you recreate their function using NAND gates?

Comment: You've got 10 digits to display. Generate a 10:1 multiplexor, using a 4:16 decoder (thus counting 1--10 produces 10 unique outputs; just ignore the other 6 possibilities). Then build a 4-wide mux that picks off the 4 bits for the selected digit; this uses AND gates and 10-input OR gate. And you need a way to COUNT, from 1 through 10, using FFs/latches. Sounds like you will learn a lot. Go for it.